# What command to use to get blocks to appear or be placed/ disappear?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making adventure and just wondering how do get blocks to be placed or gotten rid of with a command (that can be set of by a command block).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this command:

```
/setblock <x> <y> <z> <blockname> [Damage] {dataTags}
```

Where "blockname" means the block's name (ex. `minecraft:dirt`) and x y z signifies the coordinates of the place you want the block to show up (use <kbd>f3</kbd> to find these, and look on the middle left of your screen for the "Block" or "Looking At" section). Example:

```
/setblock 0 1 0 minecraft:air
```